# Crawling sub-domain with Anemone

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, anemone

I am using Anemone. How do I crawl sub-domain too? for e.g if I have website `www.abc.com` my crawler should also crawl `support.abc.com` or `blah.abc.com`. I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.

Comment: Why is this a Rails or Nokogiri question?

Comment: I removed the rails and nokogiri tags: they are not central to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a commit on Github that solves your problem.

https://github.com/runa/anemone/commit/91559bde052956cfc40ae62678ec2a61574cf928

Change your anemone gem files as per the link.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [Anemone docs](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) you can pass multiple sites into the `crawl` command:

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.abc.com/", "http://support.abc.com/", "http://blah.abc.com/")
```

Of course, your next problem will probably be ABC banning you for crawling their site, but that's a different question.

Comment: what if I don't know sub-domains?

Comment: If you don't know the subdomains you will have to try to locate them by searching through the links retrieved from the first page, looking for other sites that are sub-domains, or that appear to be sibling-domains, of the starting one. Then spawn secondary crawls.